# Why i am getting wrong sum here?

Tags: c++, average

For example if am entering 20 for 5 times then i should get sum as 100 but i am getting it 99. Its happening for all the time i am getting sum as sum-1.

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  double sum = 0, marks = 0, count = 0;
  cout << " Enter the marks, enter -1 if you want to stop: " << endl;

  while (marks >= 0) {
    cin >> marks;
    sum = sum + marks;
    if (marks != -1) {
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }

  cout << "count= " << count << "   sum=" << sum
       << endl; // Why i am getting sum-1 in here?

  if (sum == -1) {
    cout << "Please enter atleast 2 marks to calculate the average." << endl;
  } else {
    double average = sum / count;
    cout << "Average of all the marks is: " << average << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: you only add to `count` if `marks` is not equal to `-1`.  What about adding to `sum`?

Comment: You are adding -1 when you exit the loop. Make an exception so -1 is not added.

Comment: details do matter: "For example if am entering 20 for 5 times " what you are actually entering is `20 20 20 20 20 -1` and you calcualte the sum of all those numbers

Answer (score 3):

You are adding the -1(signal to stop the loop) to the total sum;
You can do something like so to solve it

```
while (marks >= 0) {
    cin >> marks;
   if (marks != -1) {
     sum = sum + marks;
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You add to `sum` regardless of the value of `marks`, so you add -1 at the end.

Read first, then check, then add, and stop when reading fails or the input is negative:

```
while (cin >> marks && marks >= 0)
{
    sum += marks;
    count += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange the loop to do the checking, done at the start of the body, right AFTER reading the next input, i.e. BEFORE the new input gets summed up and counted.

If you take the init values of counter and sum into account, this even gets rid of the `if`. This might seem less readable, less explicitly programming what you think. Consider this important. But otherwise it has some elegance.

```
double sum = 0, marks = 0, count = 0;
while (marks >= 0)
{
    sum = sum + marks; // init value 0 -> NoOp in first iteration
    count = count + 1; // count one iteration ahead
    cin >> marks;
}
count--; // undo the ahead counting
```

Alternatively init the count to -1.
Note, for things like counters an `int` is better than `double`.

```
double sum = 0, marks = 0;
int count = -1;
while (marks >= 0)
{
    sum = sum + marks; // init value  0 -> NoOp in first iteration
    count = count + 1; // init value -1 -> count to zero before first input
    cin >> marks;
}
```

On the side, trusting floating point values/variables with equality comparing is risky. If you intend to read "0.0" as valid marks, consider comparing like `while (marks > -0.0001)`. Paranoia is a healty state of mind for a programmmer...

Answer (score 0):

If we are going to analyze and read your code we could see that you made a condition which is, if variable `marks` is set as less than 0 the condition for the loop will result in false which eventually stops the loop. The cause of having your expected result having -1 is that you input or set the variable `marks` to -1 to exit the loop. But, before testing the condition of the loop again it needed to finish the codes inside the loop (except if you would make a condition to break the loop). So, after having to input -1 the code still proceeds to the next line of code which is `sum = sum + marks;` which causes your variable `sum = sum + (-1)` which leads to your inaccurate expected result.

This kind of problem can be fixed with different kinds of approaches. You could probably use a condition for `break;`. For example adding the if statement `if(marks == -1){break;}` after the `cin >> marks;`. Another approach is having another condition to end the loop instead of using the `marks` variable.

I highly suggest that if you are dealing with numbers you could use a boolean type of variable for conditions like this. This kind of problem occurs because of using a variable as a multipurpose. It is not wrong but it is sometimes causing a problem like this. Also, I recommend having a clearer condition to end a loop. Good practice in coding is a must. Have a good day!